# How to build Boost C++ on Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: c++, boost, windows-8

I want to use Boost C++ in a Windows 8 Metro app and I can't get the library built on Windows 8 via Visual Studio 11 in the Windows 8 Developer Preview. I believe this is due to the limited out-of-the-box functionality on VS 11 at this time.

The latest version of Boost (1.48.0) does not come with an installer.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

If the answer is build on Windows 7 and transfer, how do I accomplish this?

Boost C++ download: http://www.boost.org/users/download/
Boost C++ getting started: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: How exactly are you trying to build it? Note that Win32 API is severely limited for Metro apps, so some Boost libraries may not build at all. You should be able to cherry-pick those that you want, though (so long as they don't use any restricted APIs).

Comment: I suspect that many/most of the things that need to change for Boost to work are simply replacing APIs - like replacing CreateFile with CreateFileEx, etc.

Comment: @LarryOsterman: Wouldn't that be `CreateFile2`? I'm a bit shocked to see the gratuitous incompatibilities. Another one: "The `LoadPackagedLibrary` function is a simplified version of `LoadLibraryEx`. Metro style apps can [only] use `LoadPackagedLibrary` to load packaged modules. Desktop applications cannot use `LoadPackagedLibrary`".

Comment: @MSalters how is that a gratuitous incompatibility? A packaged library and a library are different.

Comment: @KateGregory: Tt's reasonable that you can't mix Win32 and Metro, just like you can't mix Win32 and Win64. But Win32 and Win64 can both use `LoadLibraryEx`, so why not Metro?

Comment: @MSalters: LoadLibrary could be used to bypass appstore regulations about which APIs are called by metro style apps, so it is blocked for all metro stile apps.  LoadPackagedLibrary can only load DLLs which are contained in the applications package.

Comment: Thank you for the insights into Metro style apps. I decided to adhere to the answer below and just grab the portions that I need until I can further explore the libraries already available.

Comment: To be clear: Every one of the APIs removed from the SDK was removed for a good reason: Many were removed because they've been superseded by newer APIs (CreateFile vs CreateFile2, etc) or because there's a windows runtime version of the API or because they cannot work in an appcontainer or because they can be used to bypass appstore restrictions (LoadLibraryEx).  None were removed gratuitously (I work with the team which is responsible for which APIs are in the SDK and they agonize over each removal).

Comment: @All: thank you for the advice on the library updates and general discussion. I decided to avoid Boost for this app for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Metro library and a desktop library are different things. Metro libraries are severely restricted. You could build the library on Windows 7 and hand-install it on your system, but that would not mean you could use it on your system from a Metro app, if it made system calls that Metro does not allow.

Rather than "all of Boost" you would be best served by trying to get the pieces you need working. If you don't use Boost to work with files, what do you care that file access must now be async, and must go through APIs that ensure your Metro app has declared the right capabilities, and so on? And of course if you are using part of Boost that is in C++11, (eg shared_ptr) save yourself a lot of trouble and use the C++11 version.

Comment: Kate, I decided to adhere to your answer and just grab the portions that I need until I can further explore the libraries already available. Thank you for saving me from a headache.